# Shortcode in a blog post, footer and related products stop working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-query, shortcode

I have a problem, I develop a shortcode, and it works fine just that when I put it in a blog post, footer and related products stop working.

I show you my code I hope you can help me.

```
<?php
add_shortcode('myshort', 'myshortBrandName');

add_shortcode('myshortother', 'myshortotherBrandArtist');

function myshortotherBrandArtist($atts){
    ob_start();
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'posts' => '',
        'artist' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    $options = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'post_type' => array (
            'post' => 'post',
        ),
        'meta_value' => $artist
    ); 

    $products = new WP_Query( $options );
    if( $products->have_posts() ) {
      ?>
      <div class="contenedorelp">
      <h3>The last post of <span><?php echo $artist; ?></span></h3>
      <?php
      while( $products->have_posts() ) {
        $products->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="relacional">
          <div class="featured-image">
         <a rel="noindex, follow" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?></a>
          </div>
          <h4><?php the_title() ?></h4>
        </div>
        <?php
      }
      ?></div>
      <?php
      return ob_get_clean();
    }
    else {
      echo 'No exist';
    }
}

function myshortBrandName($atts){
    ob_start();
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'posts' => '',
        'brand' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    $options = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_brand',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $brand
        )
      )
    ); 

    $products = new WP_Query( $options );
    if( $products->have_posts() ) {
      ?>
      <div class="contenedorel">
      <h3>The products of <?php echo $brand; ?> en la <span><img src="/wp-content/themes/neighborhood-child/images/eboutiq-flecha-sidebar.png"/> eBoutique D Talentos</span></h3>
      <?php
      while( $products->have_posts() ) {
        $products->the_post();
        $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
        ?>
        <a rel="noindex, follow" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><div class="relacional">
          <div class="featured-image">
         <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
          </div>
          <h4><span><?php the_title() ?> </span><span class="price">$ <?php echo $price; ?> MXN</span></h4>
        </div></a>
        <?php
      }
      ?></div>
      <?php
      return ob_get_clean();
    }
    else {
      echo 'No exist';
    }
}

?>
```

thank for all

Comment: Use `wp_reset_postdata()`(https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) appropriately, otherwise your `WP_Query()` can affect other queries.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

It solved well when I added:

wp_reset_query();

After closing the while

Answer (score 0):

It solved well when I added:

```
wp_reset_query();
```

After closing the while

Comment: `wp_reset_query` should only be called when using `query_posts`, which is a function that should never be used. If you use `query_posts` you should switch to `WP_Query` or using the `pre_get_posts` filter. Then, you'd use `wp_reset_postdata` to clean up